# Unable to findnodes() restricted just to current parent

Tags: perl-module

I'm parsing a simple XML file to create a flat text file from it. The desired outcome is shown below the sample XML. The XML has sort of a header-detail structure (Assembly_Info and Part respectively), with a unique header node followed by any number of detail record nodes, all of which are siblings. After digging into the elements under the header, I can't then find a way back 'up' to then pick up all the sibling detail nodes.

XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<Wrapper>
  <Record>
    <Product>
      <prodid>4094</prodid>
    </Product>
    <Assembly>
      <Assembly_Info>
        <id>DF-7A</id>
        <interface>C</interface>
      </Assembly_Info>
      <Part>
        <status>N/A</status>
        <dev_name>0000</dev_name>
      </Part>
      <Part>
        <status>Ready</status>
        <dev_name>0455</dev_name>
      </Part>
      <Part>
        <status>Ready</status>
        <dev_name>045A</dev_name>
      </Part>
    </Assembly>
    <Assembly>
      <Assembly_Info>
        <id>DF-7A</id>
        <interface>C</interface>
      </Assembly_Info>
      <Part>
        <status>N/A</status>
        <dev_name>0002</dev_name>
      </Part>
      <Part>
        <status>Ready</status>
        <dev_name>0457</dev_name>
      </Part>
     </Assembly>
  </Record>
</Wrapper>
```

For each Assembly I need to read the values of the two elemenmets in Assembly_Info which I do successfully. But, I then want to read each of the Part records that are associated with the Assembly. The objective is to 'flatten' the file into this:

```
  prodid    id      interface   status      dev_name
    4094    DF-7A   C           N/A         0000
    4094    DF-7A   C           Ready       0455
    4094    DF-7A   C           Ready       045A
    4094    DF-7A   C           N/A         0002
    4094    DF-7A   C           Ready       0457
```

I'm attempting to use findnodes() to do this, as that's about the only tool I thought I understood. My code unfortunately reads all of the Part records from the entire file foreach Assembly--since the only way I've been able to find the Part nodes is to start at the root. I don't know how to change 'where I am', if you will; to tell findnodes to begin at current parent. Code looks like this:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML -> new();
my $tree = $parser -> parse_file ('DEMO.XML');

    for my $product ($tree->findnodes ('/Wrapper/Record/Product/prodid')) {
        $prodid = $product->textContent();
    }

    foreach my $assembly ($tree->findnodes ('/Wrapper/Record/Assembly')){
        $assemblies++;
        $parts = 0;
        for my $assembly ($tree->findnodes ('/Wrapper/Record/Assembly/Assembly_Info')) {
            $id = $assembly->findvalue('id');
            $interface = $assembly->findvalue('interface');
        }

        foreach my $part ($tree->findnodes ('/Wrapper/Record/Assembly/Part')) {
            $parts++;
            $status          = $part->findvalue('status');
            $dev_name        = $part->findvalue('dev_name');
        }
        print "Assembly No: ", $assemblies, " Parts: ",$parts, "\n";
    }
```

How do I get just the Part nodes for a given Assembly, after I've gone down to the Assembly_Info depths? There is quite a bit I'm not getting, and I think a problem may be that I'm thinking of this as 'navigating' or moving a cursor, if you will. Examples of XPath path expressions have not helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always using `$tree` as the starting point for the `findnodes` method, you can use any other node, especially also child nodes. Then you could use a relative XPath expression. For example:

```
for my $record ($tree->findnodes('/Wrapper/Record')) {
    for my $assembly ($record->findnodes('./Assembly')) {
        for my $part ($assembly->findnodes('./Part')) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes--that was the solution and a plug in a serious gap in my understanding.